# Responsive website testing tools

Tags: manual-testing, qa-developer

I am testing with some responsive tools for responsible website test.But sometimes these tools don't give me equal result. Like iPhone & iPad results & tools results don't match each with others. So that I am facing new problem & I can't find out bugs. At this time which tools will be better for testing responsive website it's most important for bug tracking.If anyone can give me others tools name & also url for testing responsive websites testing so please inform me. I am testing by these Tools are:

1. http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/
2. http://www.browserstack.com/responsive

Also I had some testing tools but I didn't share because my reputation isn't 10 up.

Comment: Firefox has a built-in responsive design tool (tools > web developer > responsive design tool) and so does Chrome (in the developer tools).

Answer (score 6):

One of the options is as you have already tried - browserstack.

Then you can install android SDK on your machine. It provides an emulator for various screen sizes and android os.

For iOS you can try the xcode. I haven't used it personally but it is somewhat like the android sdk but for iOS. You will need Mac OS and iTunes store to install it.

BUT

No matter which emulator or tool you use, it will never give you proper result as the original device. The reason behind this being the difference in the environment. The environment, that is, the hardware and software that a PC operates on is different than the one's of a phone. Hence, the browsers are also different and they render webpages and their content in a different way. The emulators running on your computer will try to give you as close results to a phone as possible but never the actual result as you will get on phones. So sometimes all the emulators will do is change the screen resolution but it will not render the script as a mobile browser would.

So if you are looking for the best option is to test on the actual device!!!

Comment: It is very true what @milinpatel17 has written. I also tried many different tools both paid and free but none gives a proper result like the actual device.

Answer (score 1):

Saucelabs and Browserstack are great emulators for testing mobile devices. These services provide a wide variety of platforms that can be used for manual and automated testing. Browser development tools can also provide a way to emulate mobile devices. This will give you a good idea of how the environment will display and function with your site. With that being said, Emulation will never be as good as testing on the actual device. A risk assessment will need to be completed in order to determine your test plan coverage.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your website renders seamlessly across different devices, browsers, and OS, you need a thorough test plan. It will help if you consider responsive site design monitoring checklists, such as user interface tests, web-page loading, fonts, photos, navigation, alignments, etc. It will be challenging to carry out all these tasks manually.

You would find numerous tools for responsive testing in the market. I found [LT Browser](https://www.lambdatest.com/lt-browser) the best among them. LT Browser is offered by [LambdaTest](https://www.lambdatest.com/), which helps web developers to create responsive and cost-effective web applications easily. What you need to do is submit the URL of your site to test its responsive behaviour.

Following  are some of the best features of LT Browser:

- Mobile view debugging across 40+ device resolutions.
- Perform Web testing on multiple devices.
- You can create custom devices to view your website’s view parallely.
- Capture full page screenshots of your websites. Inbuilt developer tools for mobile website test.
- You can perform local testing of your websites without any extension or tunnel.
- Mark and share your bugs through different project management tools and shareable links.
- Network throttling to test your website over low latency networks such as slow 3G, fast 3G, online and offline.
- Touch mode for replicating smartphones.

Besides LT Browser, you can perform [mobile responsive test](https://www.lambdatest.com/responsive-test-online) of your website across 56+ pre-built mobile, tablet, laptop, and desktop viewports on the  LambdaTest platform.
Hope this helps!